# Reference for a bilinear form lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, reference-request, bilinear-form

I encountered the result below in a paper of Claude Viterbo ([Intersection de sous-variétés lagrangiennes, fonctionnelles d’action et indice des systèmes
hamiltoniens](http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_1987__115__361_0/), p. 379) that I was reading, and it does not have a reference. If anyone could provide me a reference, it would be very helpful.

> Lemma: Let $Q^t$ be a $C^1$ family of bilinear forms defined in a Hilbert space. Let $Q^t$ be nondegenerate for $t\neq 0$ and $Q^t = U_t + C_t$, where $U_t$ is positive definite with continuous inverse and $C_t$ is compact.
> If $\left.\frac{d}{dt}Q^t\right|_{t=0}$ when restricted to $\ker(Q^0)$ has signature $\sigma$ and nullity $\mu$ we have
> \begin{equation}
> \sigma - \mu \leq index(Q^{-1}) - index(Q^{+1}) \leq \sigma + \mu.
> \end{equation}

In fact, I am trying to understand the proof of proposition 8.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean "a $C^1$ family of bilinear forms" ?

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes =) I will change in the text. Thank you!

Comment: What is the role of $Q^t = U_t + C_t$ decomposition here?

Comment: @C.F.G Unfortunately I don't know. Maybe this type of Lemma is only valid to this kind of bilinear forms. But this is just a guess.  My need for a reference is also to be able to understand better the hypothesis.

Comment: At least tell us what paper you are reading?

Comment: @C.F.G yes of course!  It is "Intersection de sous-variétés lagrangiennes,
fonctionnelles d’action et indice des systèmes hamiltoniens" by Claude Viterbo. The Lemme is in Proposition 8.

Comment: There after lemma, author noted that "The proof is left to the reader". So it should not be too hard.

Comment: @C.F.G Agree! But I am still don't know how to do it. And I am not sure If I understand the lemma quite well.